# How to register event handlers for a DOM element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Help me please.
How to register event handlers for a DOM element  in backbone?

```
        <p id="init">init</p>
        <script>

$(function () {
   function Config(){
       this.el=document.getElementById('init');

   }
   var config=new Config;


_.extend(config, Backbone.Events);


function fn(){
    console.log('hello');
}
config.el.on('click',fn);

});
```

I got an error in code:

> TypeError: config.el.on is not a function

Backbone also has method on like jquery http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on

Comment: I don't think it's really orthodox to do, but you should extend `config.el`, not `config`, otherwise `config.el` will refer to the plain DOM element, not to an extended one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone.Events is a module that let object have the ability to bind and trigger custom named events.

e.g.,

```
_.extend(config,Backbone.Events);
config.on("MY_EVENT",function(msg){
    console.log("Event parameter: "+msg);
});
config.trigger("MY_EVENT","MSG");
```

So if you want to register DOM click event maybe you should register event handler in JS or jQuery way in your object constructor.

```
$(function(){
    function Config(){
        this.el = document.getElementById("test");
        $(this.el).on("click",fn);   //jQuery way
        this.el.addEventListener("click", fn, false);  //js way
    }

    var config = new Config;

    _.extend(config,Backbone.Events);

    function fn(){
        alert("hello");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`config.el` is referencing a DOM element. You are trying to call a jQuery method (`on()`), you'll need to turn that DOM reference to a jQuery object:

```
$(config.el).on('click',fn);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfkY9/)

Or without jQuery

```
config.el.onclick = fn;
```

Another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfkY9/3)

Comment: how to do it without jquery events?